# What is the namespace of Google.Apis.Authentication;

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to use [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) to download a file from Google Drive using dotnet.
The problem is, I can't find this namespace in the nuget - using Google.Apis.Authentication; .

I'v downloaded everything that has the name 'Google' in nuget, but no luck.

Any idea where it can hide? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access Google drive the only nugget package you need to download is [PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/).  It will automatically add anything else you need.

**My download from drive method**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Download a file
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_service">a Valid authenticated DriveService</param>
        /// <param name="_fileResource">File resource of the file to download</param>
        /// <param name="_saveTo">location of where to save the file including the file name to save it as.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Boolean downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl );
                    byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
                    return true;                  
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                return false;
            }
        }
```

code ripped from [google drive sample project](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a better sample for you (in the official samples repo, https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/Drive.Sample/Program.cs#L154).

```
    ...
    await DownloadFile(service, uploadedFile.DownloadUrl);
    ...

    /// <summary>Downloads the media from the given URL.</summary>
    private async Task DownloadFile(DriveService service, string url)
    {
        var downloader = new MediaDownloader(service);
        var fileName = <PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE>
        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,
            System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var progress = await downloader.DownloadAsync(url, fileStream);
            if (progress.Status == DownloadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName + " was downloaded successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download {0} was interpreted in the middle. Only {1} were downloaded. ",
                    fileName, progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
        }
    }
```

More documentation about media download is available here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download